# Trigger the event of a Key despite the eventual modifiers

Tags: java, key-bindings

I'm starting to use KeyBinding in java and i have some issues with the key modifiers ( shift, ctrl ...) who prevent my KeyBinding to work.

For example, if i press "x", the appropriate Action is triggered, but when i'm pressing "x" while "shift" is also pressed, nothing happened.

```
panel = p;
panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X,0,false), "shoot");
//work only if x is "raw", without modifiers pressed
panel.getActionMap().put("shoot",new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        shoot=true;         
    }});
```

I understand that it is the way that work, but i was wondering if there is a way to said "I want this key without or with any modifier" rather than write a line for each modifiers.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What I would do, if it's important to you, is make a number of bindings, including the modifiers you want to use and assign them all to the `"shoot"` key, that way, they will all trigger the `"shoot"` action

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well if there is no other way i guess i'll have to write some bunch of line, Thanks anyway ^^.

Comment: Well, it’s one extra line for each modifier you want to use, I’d just build a helper method which can bind it all together